# IsMouseOver for Button triggered when mouse it over the textblock, not entire button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following layout:

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle} >
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">MyText</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Style is defined as following:

```
<Style x:Key="BackButtonStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="GridArea"
                            Padding="8,4"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenterArea"/>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridArea" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Some_Brush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The problem is that background brush changes only when mouse is over the textblock, not the entire area. I tried few things but with no effect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridArea` has `null` Background. Elements with `null` Background don't react to mouse. set `Background="Transparent"` or better yet use TemplateBindings:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="GridArea"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="8,4"
                Margin="0,0,0,0">
```